# Adding submenu to custom plugin menu page created with add_menu_page() function

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, add-menu-page, add-submenu-page

I have created a custom menu page using add_menu_page() function. Everything in that page appears as it should in the screen. What I am trying to achieve is adding another submenu under the under the page i previously created(i want it to appear just like when you click on the settings menu in `wordpress` dashboard). I am pasting a code snippet below:

```
    //creating the menu item for the plugin
function qpv_custom_menu_link() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Quick Product View Options',
        'Quick Product View',
        'manage_options',
        'qpv-options',
        'qpv_options_page',
        '',
        '100'
    );
    add_submenu_page(
        'qpv-options',
        'Quick Product View Appearance',
        'Quick Product View Appearance Settings',
        'manage-options',
        'qpva-options',
        'qpva_options_page'
    );


}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'qpv_custom_menu_link' );


//creating the submenu page settings
function qpva_options_page(){

    ob_start(); ?>

    <h2>Hello</h2>


    <?php
    echo ob_get_clean();
}
```

I have also checked the [`wordpress` codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) and have followed the given instructions, but my problem remains and the submenu page still does not show up in under the plugin name.

Comment: I know I have found myself in this same situation over and over, and that the solution was very easy, and yet I can't find it again.

Answer (score 1):

You may take use of `add_submenu_page` function:

**Add a top-level menu page**

```
add_menu_page(
    $page_title,
    $menu_title,
    $capability,
    $menu_slug,
    $function,
    $icon_url,
    $position
);
```

**Add a sub-menu page**

```
add_submenu_page(
    $parent_slug,
    $page_title,
    $menu_title,
    $capability,
    $menu_slug,
    $function
);
```

Comment: that's what i did if you check my code above you 'll see that. But thank you for your time.

Comment: No, u did not. the `add_submenu_page` accepts only 6 arguments, but you have passed 8. Thank yourself for your time :).

Comment: I have done that also and i tried it again. But no submenu to be found under my plugin. Shouldn't i get a page as a submenu that says hello or am i wrong?

Comment: Any new idea???